# flutter firebase MissingPluginException

Tags: firebase, flutter, initialization

I just added firebase to my flutter App, i followed all the steps correctly, but i'm getting an error when initializing the app

this is my code to initialize app

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: new ThemeData(
        canvasColor: Colors.white,
      ),
      home: PersistentTabsDemo(),
      onGenerateRoute: route.controller,
    );
  }
}
```

this are the dependecies i added to pubsec.yaml

```
  firebase_core: ^1.6.0
  firebase_analytics: ^8.3.1
  firebase_auth: ^3.1.0
  cloud_firestore: ^2.5.1
```

and this is the error

```
Error: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method Firebase#initializeCore on channel
plugins.flutter.io/firebase_core)
```

Edit: i tried removing async and await from my main class now i'm getting new error

```
No firebase App 'default' has been created - call Firebase.intializeApp()
```

Comment: Restart android studio . Check sh1 key is added to firebase setting.And did you added json file to android /app directory.

Comment: yes i've already done all of that

Comment: Are you running the app on windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else had the same issue as me

I've fixed the issue by creating another project and added the sh1 and sh256 to firebase
just follow this tuto it's really helpful https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CpyALC8Zpxo

PS: when u add firebase to your flutter project don't run it on chrome debug you will get an error, run it on your emulator or smartphone

happy coding ^^

Comment: Right, but that's the problem. It's not working on Chrome. Any success on getting it to work on Chrome yet?

Answer (score 0):

Try
Flutter clean
Pub.get
If these two doesn't work
Something is missing in setup of Firebase flutter

Comment: @Kanak Joshi yes i'am runing it on windows